# Rails4.2 Devise + omniauthでソーシャルログイン時はメール認証とメール送信をスキップしたい。

Tags: ruby-on-rails

omniauthを使ってFacebook、Twitterのログインと通常のメールアドレス登録を実装しています。
deviseでメール認証する(confirmable)ようにしました。。
FacebookとTwitterのログインのときには、メール認証せずにログインするようにしたいので
下記のように`@user.skip_confirmation!`を追加し無事認証はできるようになったのですが
認証メールが送られる状態です。どうすればメールを送らないようにできるでしょうか？

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

  def facebook
    callback_from :facebook
  end

  def twitter
    callback_from :twitter
  end

  private

  def callback_from(provider)
    provider = provider.to_s

    @user = User.find_for_oauth(request.env['omniauth.auth'])
    @user.skip_confirmation!
    if @user.persisted?
      flash[:notice] = I18n.t('devise.omniauth_callbacks.success', kind: provider.capitalize)
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, event: :authentication
    else
      if provider == 'twitter'
        session["devise.twitter_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"].except("extra")
      else
        session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      end
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user.save!で保存してしまう

```
def callback_from(provider)
    provider = provider.to_s

    @user = User.find_for_oauth(request.env['omniauth.auth'])
    @user.skip_confirmation!
    @user.save!
    if @user.persisted?
      flash[:notice] = I18n.t('devise.omniauth_callbacks.success', kind: provider.capitalize)
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, event: :authentication
    else
      if provider == 'twitter'
        session["devise.twitter_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"].except("extra")
      else
        session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      end
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
```